# Filezilla permission denied

Tags: filezilla

I am trying to copy some files from my Windows machine to my Ubuntu VPS. I use the same login for Filezilla as I use for login to Ubuntu. But when I try to copy something I get the following error:

```
Command: CWD /home/johan/vbox
Answer: 250 Directory successfully changed.
Assignment: TYPE I
Answer: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
Assignment: PASV
Answer: 227 Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xx,xx,160,86).
Assignment: STOR W2019Docker.ovf
Answer: 550 Permission denied.
Error: Fatal File Transfer Error
```

I am just entering the world of Linux so maybe I still need to configure on the Linux site?

Thanks!

Comment: Could this be caused by the `W2019Docker.ovf` file being too big to upload? What is your FTP max upload size, and how big is the OVF file?

Comment: are you 100% sure that u have write permissions to that folder with that username? login with ssh and try to create a file in that folder with `touch /home/johan/vbox/test.file`